# ListView in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-loadermanager

I am developing an application for android 2.2, in which I would like to have a `ListView` with the possibility of `onLongClickListener` method. So far I have been using [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), but now I got stuck at `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` because my eclipse claims that it can't find the method. I've got this:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

public class SBNextends extends ListActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

private TextView tView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.sbn);
    tView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sbn);
    tView.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < MyDataLoader.getData.size(); i++) {
        tView.append(MyDataLoader.dataListONE.get(i));
    }
    String[] from = new String[MyDataLoader.dataListONE.size()];
            for(int i = 0; MyDataLoader.dataListONE.size()> i; i++) {
            from[i] = MyDataLoader.dataListONE.get(i);  
            }
    int[] toView = {android.R.id.text1};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, toView);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Any one got any ideas of why I can't use the `getLoaderManager()` method? I have imported the support libraries

Comment: When I start typing `LoaderM` in Eclipse, all the suggestions about classes disappears, so somehow it can't find the class I think

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to be consistent with the base classes that you use: either from compatibility package, either from `android.app` one. In your case you're extending from `android.app.ListActivity`, so replace:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
```

with:

```
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
```

But in this case, you're not actually running against 2.2. So you better stick with compatibility package by extending from `FragmentActivity` and make your own `FragmentListActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

It is how I use LoaderCallbacks on v4 apps.

Instead of using **ListActivity**, use **FragmentActivity**. In this case, you have to instance your ListView by findViewById as it wouln't automatically instance your ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;   
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }
```